# container_class isn't being applied for wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add a `wordpress menu` to my wordpress theme and when I follow the specified instructions online, it doesn't work.

I have this in `functions.php`

```
<?php

function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'sidebar-menu' => __( 'Sidebar Menu' )
     )
   );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

In `sidebar.php` of my theme theme I have this code

```
       <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
          array(
            'theme_location' => 'sidebar-menu',
            'container_class' => 'sidebar'
          )
        ); 
        ?>
```

But when I inspect the HTML code that is outputted, my menu doesn't have the `sidebar` class on it, instead it is given a `menu` class.

Why?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I've just come across the exact same issue

Comment: Not really no. I've asked on the wordpress forums and there's no workarounds, only stopgaps, which is to create CSS rules to style the HTML element you don't really want there, regardless. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-remove-the-container-div-from-menus-appearing-in-a-widget/

Answer (score 1):

It gives you a `<div class="sidebar"><ul class="menu">...</ul></div>` (default wrapper is `<div>` tag)

if you want to change class on `<ul>` tag, you should add param `menu_class`:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'sidebar-menu',
        'container_class' => 'wrapper_class',
        'menu_class'      => 'sidebar',
    )
);
```

if you don't need wrapper `<div class="wrapper_class">`, then

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'sidebar-menu',
        'container'       => false, 
        'menu_class'      => 'sidebar',

    )
);
```